# how do you replace only a certain number of items in a list randomly?

Tags: python-3.x

```
board = []
for x in range(0,8):
    board.append(["0"] * 8)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(row))
```

this code creates a grid of zeros but I wish to replace 5 of them with ones and another five with twos

does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to randomly set some coordinates with "1" and "2", you can do it like this:

```
import random

board = []
for x in range(0, 8):
    board.append(["0"] * 8)


def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(row))


def generate_coordinates(x, y, k):
    coordinates = [(i, j) for i in range(x) for j in range(y)]
    random.shuffle(coordinates)
    return coordinates[:k]


coo = generate_coordinates(8, 8, 10)
ones = coo[:5]
twos = coo[5:]

for i, j in ones:
    board[i][j] = "1"

for i, j in twos:
    board[i][j] = "2"


print_board(board)
```

**Output**

```
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 2 0 0 2
2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Notes:

- The code above generates a random sample each time so the output will be different each time (to generate the same use `random.seed(42)`, you can change `42` for any number you want.
- The function `generate_coordinates` receives `x` (number of rows), `y` (number of columns) and k (the number of coordinates to pick). It generates a sequence of coordinates of x*y, shuffles it and picks the `k` first.
- In your specific case x = 8, y = 8 and k = 10 (5 for the ones and 5 for the twos)

Finally, this picks the positions for the ones and twos and changes the values:

```
ones = coo[:5]
twos = coo[5:]

for i, j in ones:
    board[i][j] = "1"

for i, j in twos:
    board[i][j] = "2"
```